# What does binding to Object do in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to understand the `D3.js` code for [this example](http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/) and am confused by this code:

```
var circle = interpolation.selectAll("circle")
    .data(Object);
circle.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("fill","yellow");
circle
    .attr("cx", function y(d) { console.log(d.attr("class")); return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

What does the second line of this code actually do? What data does it bind to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data bound in the element above that is given by the function `getLevels(d, t)`, where `d` is a number of range 2 - 4 and `t` is a number derived from the current time.

This only ever returns an array of arrays. Because an array is [already of type Object](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html), Calling Object() on an Array returns the original array.. Therefore, from what I can see, the author is simply using Object as a kind of identity function, similar to:

```
var identity = function(d){
  return d;
}

var circle = interpolation.selectAll("circle")
    .data(identity);
circle.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("fill","yellow");
circle
    .attr("cx", function y(d) { console.log(d.attr("class")); return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

Comment: Thanks, minikomi. I have never seen `Object` being used as an identity function before so I was confused by this. I replaced `Object` with `function(d) { return d; }` and it works as well. Thanks for a very clear explanation.

Comment: No problem. It was a bit of a head scratcher for me too.